# React add event to transition user to a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In react I have the following component that is repeated for every service I want to sell. When the user clicks the button I want to build a custom url for them to go to. I am using react router dom. Here is the code I have for the button

```
<button
  className="w-full block text-white py-4 rounded-sm"
  style={{ background: "#48746e" }}
  onClick={this.navigateToRoute}
>
  Continue booking
</button>
```

Now I can access all the data I need to build the url but I do not know how to perform the transition to take them to that route. Thanks for any tips

Comment: @Muath that link is to angular not react

Comment: your right bro didnt focus my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call inside this.navigateToRoute

```
<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
```

or if you need to pass state:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```